# Give a derivation of the following formal theorems:

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, solution-verification

Show, φ, (φ $\Rightarrow$ ψ), (φ $\Rightarrow$ (ψ $\Rightarrow$ θ)) $\vdash$ θ

Here is my answer, please let me know if I'm doing this correctly!

1. φ $\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$< Hypothesis 1>
2. φ $\Rightarrow$ ψ  $\qquad$$\qquad$ < Hypothesis 2>
3. φ $\Rightarrow$ (ψ $\Rightarrow$ θ)$\qquad$< Hypothesis 3>
4. ψ $\Rightarrow$ θ $\qquad$$\qquad$ <1,3 + Equanimity>
5. φ $\Rightarrow$ θ $\qquad$ $\qquad$<2,4 + Transitivity>
6. θ $\qquad$$\qquad$$\qquad$<1,5 + Equanimity>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is **correct**.

Well, the names are unfamiliar, but the steps *are* valid inferences.

"Equanimity" appears to be "Modus Ponens" and "Transitivity" is "Hypothetical Syllogism".

---

You *may* also do it without "Transitivity", if you wish.

1. $φ\qquad \qquad \qquad~~$< Hypothesis 1>
2. $φ \to ψ  \qquad\qquad$ < Hypothesis 2>
3. $φ \to (ψ \to θ)\quad~$< Hypothesis 3>
4. $ψ \qquad\qquad\qquad$ <1,2 + Equanimity>
5. $ψ \to θ \qquad\qquad$ <1,3 + Equanimity>
6. $θ \qquad\qquad\qquad$ <4,5 + Equanimity>

Comment: I've been struggling to figure out the proper way of explaining my steps because my prof uses different terms (based off the textbook Mathematical Logic by George Tourlakis, 2008) than what I'm seeing online. I appreciate the help regardless though!